# import class from external madule does not work in NodeJS

Tags: node.js, import

I'm pretty new to Node.js and try to learn it for my work.
I want to import a class name "IgApiClient" from a file with name "client.ts"
the file exists in "core" folder which it exists in "src" folder.
the file I try to run is under "example" folder which it and "src" are in one folder.

Here is screenshots of what I said:

[first](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EXBi2.jpg)

[second](https://i.stack.imgur.com/btSef.jpg)

I think I should use the import statement for this as below:

```
import { IgApiClient } from '../src';
```

which is for nodejs version before 13 and for ver 13 and above I should use this as below:

```
const { IgApiClient } = require('../src');
```

I'm using the second one for my purpose.
But when I run the code it get me this error:

[the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oKgJ5.jpg)

I also tried to move the "client" file to "node_modules" folder and replace "../src" with "../src/core/client", but none of them worked.
what's wrong with it?
How can I solve it?
If anyone has a better idea for this I appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Use babel to use ES6 feature like classes in NodeJs. You check this as an example [babel-node](https://github.com/babel/babel/tree/master/packages/babel-node).